# Understanding Primary annotation in Profile

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, autowired, spring-annotations

I am trying to understand the behaviour of @Primary in @Profile from this [video](https://www.udemy.com/course/spring-core/learn/lecture/4334034#questions/9003796)

Dependency Injection using profile.
    The active profile in file application.properties is `english` and running it gives error

`expected single matching bean but found 2: helloWorldServiceEnglish,helloWorldServiceSpanish`

Adding @Primary annotation in helloConfig.java  resolves the error:

```
    @Bean
    @Profile("english")
    @Primary
    public HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceEnglish(HelloWorldFactory factory) {
        return factory.createHelloWorldService("en");
    }
```

When I am Autowiring using Profile and there is only one single Profile named `english` then why it is searching for other beans which do not have @Profile annotation? And how adding @Primary is changing this behaviour?

Does Spring internally first scans for Autowire by type and completely ignore @Profile because of which it throws error  `expected single matching bean but found 2`.

*helloConfig.java*

```
package com.spring.config;

import com.spring.services.HelloWorldFactory;
import com.spring.services.HelloWorldService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Profile;

@Configuration
public class HelloConfig {

    @Bean
    public HelloWorldFactory helloWorldFactory() {
        return new HelloWorldFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("english")
    @Primary
    public HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceEnglish(HelloWorldFactory factory) {
        return factory.createHelloWorldService("en");
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("spanish")
    public HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceSpanish(HelloWorldFactory factory) {
        return factory.createHelloWorldService("es");
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("french")
    public HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceFrench(HelloWorldFactory factory) {
        return factory.createHelloWorldService("fr");
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("german")
    public HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceGerman(HelloWorldFactory factory) {
        return factory.createHelloWorldService("de");
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("polish")
    public HelloWorldService helloWorldServicePolish(HelloWorldFactory factory) {
        return factory.createHelloWorldService("pl");
    }

    @Bean
    @Profile("russian")
    public HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceRussian(HelloWorldFactory factory) {
        return factory.createHelloWorldService("ru");
    }
}
```

*DependencyInjectionApplication.java*

```
package com.spring.componentScan;

import com.spring.controllers.GreetingController;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.spring")
public class DependencyInjectionApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(DependencyInjectionApplication.class, args);
        GreetingController controller = (GreetingController) ctx.getBean("greetingController");
        controller.sayHello();
    }
}
```

*GreetingController.java*

```
package com.spring.controllers;

import com.spring.services.HelloWorldService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    private HelloWorldService helloWorldService;
    private HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceSpanish;

    @Autowired
    public void setHelloWorldService(HelloWorldService helloWorldService) {
        this.helloWorldService = helloWorldService;
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("spanish")
    public void setHelloWorldServiceFrench(HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceSpanish) {
        this.helloWorldServiceSpanish = helloWorldServiceSpanish;
    }

    public String sayHello() {
        String greeting = helloWorldService.getGreeting();
        System.out.println(helloWorldServiceSpanish.getGreeting());
        System.out.println(greeting);
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

*Application.properties*
    spring.profiles.active=english

[Complete Source code:](https://github.com/Akshay9882/Spring/tree/AdvancedAutoWiring)

Answer (score 0):

If you consider this source code

```
@Bean(name = "french")
public HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceFrench(HelloWorldFactory factory) {
    return factory.createHelloWorldService("fr");
}

@Bean
public HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceGerman(HelloWorldFactory factory) {
    return factory.createHelloWorldService("de");
}

@Bean
public HelloWorldService helloWorldServicePolish(HelloWorldFactory factory) {
    return factory.createHelloWorldService("pl");
}

@Bean
public HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceRussian(HelloWorldFactory factory) {
    return factory.createHelloWorldService("ru");
}
```

here is no `@Profile` annotation, and thats why Spring creating multiple beans of same type, if you want them to recognized differently, try giving them well qualified explicit name by `@Bean(name="polish")` (or Spring anyway assign them by looking at `@Bean` method name)  and then autowire using `@Qualifier("polish")`

Comment: Actually spring creates qualifier for bean automatically using methods names. So here it would be `helloWorldServiceFrench`, `helloWorldServiceGerman ` ... that's not the main issue. Although you are right about `@Profile` annotation, it should be used for every specific implementation.

Comment: I am trying to understand the behaviour of primary in my question and not looking for any alternate solution @sagarr

Comment: I have updated my question maybe i am clear now?@sagarr. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so your example is not updated with the latest code. But I assume that you want to create multiple instances of the same bean type and use them for different languages. It's easy to achieve and you don't need to have `@Profile` and `@Primary` for that.

What you need is just assign qualifier for the bean instance (or use the one that spring assigns by default). And the inject bean by this qualifier.

```
@Bean
public HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceFrench(HelloWorldFactory factory) {
    return factory.createHelloWorldService("fr");
}

@Bean
public HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceGerman(HelloWorldFactory factory) {
    return factory.createHelloWorldService("de");
}

@Bean
public HelloWorldService helloWorldServicePolish(HelloWorldFactory factory) {
    return factory.createHelloWorldService("pl");
}

@Bean
public HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceRussian(HelloWorldFactory factory) {
    return factory.createHelloWorldService("ru");
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
    @Qualifier("helloWorldServiceGerman")
    @Autowired
    private HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceGerman;
    @Qualifier("helloWorldServiceFrench")
    @Autowired
    private HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceFrench;
    @Qualifier("helloWorldServicePolish")
    @Autowired
    private HelloWorldService helloWorldServicePolish;
    @Qualifier("helloWorldServiceRussian")
    @Autowired
    private HelloWorldService helloWorldServiceRussian;
    . . .
}
```

### Update

You usually mark a bean as `@Primary` when you want to have one bean instance as a priority option when there are multiple injection candidates. [Official doc with good example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Primary.html).

`@Profile` just narrows bean search, but still if you have multiple beans of the same type in the same profile - `@Primary` to the rescue (if you autowire by type, autowire by qualifier still works fine though).

Developers usually do this to avoid `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` that you had initially.

Comment: I am trying to understand the behaviour of primary in my question and not looking for any alternate solution @rxn1d

Comment: Updated my previous answer

Comment: I have updated my question maybe i am clear now?@rxn1d. Sorry